# ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named selenium whereas it is installed in my virt env

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, pycharm, virtualenv

I use PyCharm Edu 2018.3, with a virtual environment path set outside my python application root folder (I use this environment for other python code).
When i run the program from PyCharm, it works without errors. But when i run it from a .bat file it fail to be able to import the packages from my environment.
Basically, it seems like all installed packages made in the environment, are not being found when launched from the .bat file. 
So i was wondering if the fact that my environment was outside my root python code was an issue or if i had to precise a path, or else.
All packages imported are correctly inatlled in my envirnment and the code runs as expected when run in PyCharm.
Also, i tried to run a simple "Hello World' code from my .bat file and it works correctly, so issue only occurs when calling packages from my environment.
Could it be a setup file issue (i have none)?
Thank for the help and suggestions.

For instance, the import of selenium which is my first import, in the code, triggers the following error:

#

from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement import FirefoxWebElement as MyWeb
Element
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'

#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you have either installed `selenium` to the `virtualenv` that PyCharm setup for you when executing from withing the IDE.  However When your running outside of the IDE you are using the default python interpreter not your `virtualenv`.  To ensure your in the expected `virtualenv` make sure it's activated before running.

So for example

```
$ cd C:\Users\'Username'\venv\Scripts\
$ activate.bat
```

From this point you should be able to execute your `bat` script using that `virtualenv`.

If your still getting it with the `virtualenv` activated then try installing with `pip` while your `virtualenv` is activated.

Comment: It should be inside the `Scripts` folder inside your virtualenv you created

Comment: I ended up using .bat pointing to python.exe in the env, which doesn't need activate. Thanks for prompt answer, helped me a lot, as i thought issue was elsewhere in env path...